# Integer.parseInt() Exception handling concept

Tags: java, numberformatexception

`Integer.parseInt()` in Java is declared to throw `NumberFormatException`, and it is a checked exception as I think. I have read somewhere that the checked exceptions should be either caught or thrown on the calling method. But we do not need to do it with `NumberFormatException`. I am confused. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the regular code to use `Interger.parseInt()`:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(string);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //code
}
```

But you could use the following (it catches all exceptions):

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(string);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //code
}
```

Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that we do not need to check for `NumberFormatException`s.

A checked exception is an exception that could be thrown by a method you're calling and that you're checking for it and handling it appropriately. In the example you're giving, on `NumberFormatException` you might want to let the user know that they provided an invalid number.

Basically all exceptions should be checked and handled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The function signature of parseInt() is: public static int parseInt(String string) throws NumberFormatException  . I thought NumberFormatException is a checked exception so must be caught or declared to be thrown otherwise it produces compiler error. But with a little more research I found that It extends IllegalArgumentException and IllegalArgumentException extends RuntimeException. So not catching is not a compiler error.Is it true?